# How to send custom Payload from Dialogflow fulfilment

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to send custom payload from the webhook (Firebase Cloud Function) but I am not able to achieve what I am trying. In response I wanna get something like:

```
"fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "First question."
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "What is your name?"
        ]
      }
    },
    "payload": {
      "deplay": "13 seconds"
    }
  ]
```

But right now I don't know how to add Payload in the fulfillmentMessages Array. My current code is:

```
let response = ['First question.', 'What is your name?'];
agent.add(response);
```

I have tried this

```
agent.add(new Payload('PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED', JSON.stringify(json)));
```

But then it does not send fulfillmentMessages array. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add `{ sendAsMessage=true, rawPayload=false }` in your response like this `agent.add(new Payload('PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED', JSON.stringify(json)), { sendAsMessage=true, rawPayload=false });`.

Comment: Let me try this and verify.

Comment: Sure.. give it a try. I am using the same method.

Comment: I am getting an error: SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Comment: This is the correct way  ==>>>  Payload('PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED', JSON.stringify(json)), { sendAsMessage:true, rawPayload:false });